# Make footer (not a direct child of body) stick to bottom in Flexbox based layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a website with a footer that I want to stick to the bottom of the page. In my case, there's also a sidebar, making the structure a tad more complex than just *main* and *footer* inside the html body.

The typical recommendation to make the body *min-height: 100vh*, and the main content *flex-grow: 1* does not work in my case.

How can I make the footer stick to the bottom in the code sample below? I am hoping for a flexbox-based solution.

```css
body {
}

#outer-container {
    display: flex;
}

#inner-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer-container">
    <aside>ASIDE</aside>
    <div id="inner-container">
      <main>MAIN</main>
      <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you considered grid and display: contents on the inner element?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think I have an idea of what you're suggesting, but I don't completely understand what that would be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: flex;` to the parent and `flex-grow: 1;` to the child. Also, add `min-height: 100vh;` to the `#inner-container`.

See the snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#outer-container {
  display: flex;
}

#inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer-container">
    <aside>ASIDE</aside>
    <div id="inner-container">
      <main>MAIN</main>
      <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression this would not work with *flex-grow: 1;* on *#inner-container* (which i need), but your answer made me check that again.

Answer (score 1):

By default the height is undefined and will be calculated to `fit-content`. YOu need to add a `min-height: 100vh` to the container to utilize the entire screen as a minimum. Then the easiest way to push the footer to the bottom is by giving in a `margin-top: auto`

```css
#outer-container {
    display: flex;
}

#inner-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* added */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#outer-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer-container">
    <aside>ASIDE</aside>
    <div id="inner-container">
      <main>MAIN</main>
      <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```